# Does solution of heat equation increase in time if the source term is positive?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation

Let $u_t - \Delta u = f$ hold with $u(0) = u_0 \geq 0$ on a bounded domain where $u_0$ is in $H^1$. We take Dirichlet boundary conditions.

If $f \geq0 $, is it true that $u$ is increasing in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the equation
$$
\begin{cases}u_t-u_{xx}=\sin x,& t>0,\quad0< x<\pi\\
u(x,0)=\sin x, & 0\le x\le\pi\\
u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0 & t\ge0.
\end{cases}
$$
Its solution is
$$
u(x,t)=e^{-t}\sin x+\sin x,
$$
which is decreasing in time.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it helps if the BC is Neumann? Then i test with $1$ and get $\int u(t) \geq \int u_0 \geq 0.$

Comment: No. Consider $u(x,t)=1+e^{-t}\cos x$ (with $f=0$.)